# What is the best way to conditionally serve static files in Express?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm building an application that has two separate parts to it, which on the frontend I am building as **two separate Angular apps**. I am doing it this way so that I can better divide control access to he codebase and not unnecessarily give some team members access to code they do not need.

So there are two separate applications, served from the same NodeJS server. The app that is served depends on whether the user is logged in. If they are a guest user, they get one version app, if they are registered user they get a privileged version of the app with more features.

How can I conditionally/dynamically serve static files in Express, so as to say, "if `User1` is a guest, serve `Application A`, otherwise serve `Application B`"?

Comment: have different repositories

Comment: @Aravind Ok so they are completely separate projects. Now how does the web server serve the appropriate app?

Comment: different end points.

Comment: @Aravind then it's dependent on the user to know which one to go to. I want the user to be oblivious. The user should just go to `https://sparkcryptotools.com` and get the correct app.

Comment: How do you recognize the user? By a login? Then the login part should be common.

Comment: @Skyler Yes the login page could be accessed by visiting (or clicking a link to a) `'/login` endpoint

Comment: You could store user in server session and without using express.static you can serve conditionally (checking session for user) in your endpoints.

Comment: @Skyler How do you serve static files conditionally? That's my original question. In the docs, the only way is to say `app.use(express.static...)` but that would apply to app-wide

Comment: `router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if(session.user==='xxx'){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/views1/', 'index.html'));
  }else{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/views2/', 'index.html'));
  }
})`
Something like above wouldnt work? Im just suggesting. It cannot be done if you have a lot of static files though.

Comment: @Skyler Ya I don't think that'll work with a large Angular app, which includes lots of assets like jpgs, etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's just one file you're talking about serving (e.g. `app-1.js` or `app-2.js`) then you don't need `express.static`.  You can just handle the request in a normal route handler with `res.sendFile` like so:

```
app.get('/get-app', function(req, res) {
  if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
    res.sendFile('/path-to-logged-in-app.js')
  } else {
    res.sendFile('/path-to-logged-out-app.js')
  }
})
```

More about `res.sendFile` [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile).

If you want to serve multiple files via `express.static`, you'll need two instances of `express.static` middleware, and another piece of middleware on top of that to modify the request url depending up on the user's logged in status.  Maybe something along the lines of the following:

```
// Middleware function to modify the request url based on user's status
function checkUser(req, res, next) { 
 if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
    req.url = `/app-1/${req.url}`
  } else {
    req.url = `/app-2/${req.url}`
  }

  next()
}

// Set up the middleware stack
app.use(checkUser)
app.use('/app-1', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app-1')))
app.use('/app-2', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app-2')))
```

More about writing your own middleware [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).  You also might want to add some logic in `checkUser` to only prepend to urls requesting static files (e.g. request urls to `/assets/foo.js` get the prepend treatment but requests to `/api/some-api-function` do not).

**All that said**, I'm not that familiar with Angular but I'd suggest investigating other ways to serve logged in / logged out content.  I'm assuming there is some concept of components or "views" in Angular, and it's probably a lot cleaner to just render a "LoggedIn" or "LoggedOut" component/view vs. sending a whole different "app".

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip. I think that is a decent solution but it will require me to have a completely separate endpoint for one of the apps (i.e. I'll have to put one at `https://sparkcryptotools.com/` and one at `https://sparkcryptotools.com/authed`

Comment: actually the solution proposed here is better, since it rewrites the url directly in express. that way you would still have only one endpoint, and no  http redirect causing additional requests, both apps will be served by http://yourdomain.com/get-app there will only be one endpoint, the benefit of this solution is also that it will be oblivious to the user which app he actually got

Comment: I deleted my answer in favor of this one, since it also satisfies the added requirement of the user not being made aware of the redirect

Comment: @CodyBugstein In the example above the there are no separate endpoints.  The client always makes a request using the same `req.url` regardless, and you prepend a path segment to get to the appropriate app directory.