# Why is req.session undefined when I am checking user is logged in so that I can conditionally serve static files?

Tags: node.js

Once the user logs in, I am trying to serve static files. I applied the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616368/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-serve-static-files-in-express) and I am having difficulty implementing it.

Upon log-in, I have this inside of routes.js:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    AM.manualLogin(req.body['user'], req.body['pass'], function(e, o){
        if (!o){
            res.status(400).send(e);
        } else {
            req.session.user = o;
            if (req.body['remember-me'] == 'true'){
                res.cookie('user', o.user, { maxAge: 900000 });
                res.cookie('pass', o.pass, { maxAge: 900000 });
            }
            console.log(req.session);
            res.status(200).send(o);
        }
    });
});
```

where I am setting the user in the request's session.

Inside app.js I have:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var app = express();

app.locals.pretty = true;
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/app/public' }));

function isLoggedIn( req, res, next ) {
    console.log(req.session);
    if (typeof req.session.user == undefined) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }

    next();
 }


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/public'));
app.use('/home', isLoggedIn, express.static(__dirname + "/app/server/docs"));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'faeb4453e5d14fe6f6d04637f78077c76c73d1b4',
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ url: process.env.DB_URL })
  })
);

require('./app/server/routes')(app);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

where I am conditionally trying to render the static files for `/home`.

The problem resides in `isLoggedIn` where req.session is always undefined even though it is defined in my router function. Why is this? My log statements show that is is being set, but somehow is lost inside `isLoggedIn`.

Comment: Your `app.js` logic makes sense. What is `AM.manualLogin`? and why is `/` a post request?

Comment: @ColinMichaelFlaherty Glad to know I'm partially there ;). `AM` is where my account management logic resides. I borrowed it from here (https://github.com/braitsch/node-login/blob/master/app/server/modules/account-manager.js). `/` is the path to the login page where we are making the post request to sign-in upon tapping Sign In (full disclosure - I'm a mobile dev trying to figure this out so I'm unacquainted with route naming conventions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One potential problem I see is your `app.use(session(...));` is placed after your `app.use('/home', isLoggedIn, ...);`. Hence, the session is not being properly loaded in when visiting the `/home` path. Try placing the `app.use(session(...));` middleware before the `app.use('/home', isLoggedIn, ...);` middleware.

This is due the fact that the execution of middleware is determined by the order of loading (i.e. if it's higher in your code, it's executed first).

Comment: I should've asked this 8 hours ago lol! Thank you. This was all I needed to do.

Comment: @MichaelMcKenna Glad that fixed everything :)